# Wrap p tag around text( treat single and double line breaks differently)

Tags: php

I'm  trying to figure out how to wrap text like this using php:

```
Article

Morbi nisl tortor, consectetur vitae laoreet eu, lobortis id ipsum. Integer scelerisque blandit pulvinar. 
Nam tempus mi eget nunc laoreet venenatis. Proin viverra, erat at accumsan tincidunt, ante mi cursus elit, non

Fogsu
congue mauris dolor ac elit. Maecenas mollis nisl a sem semper ornare. Integer nunc purus, dapibus nec dignissim sed, dictum eget leo. Etiam in mi ut erat pretium fringilla sed
```

To something like this:

```
<p class=single>Article</p>

<p class="double">
Morbi nisl tortor, consectetur vitae laoreet eu, lobortis id ipsum. Integer scelerisque blandit pulvinar.</p>
<p class="single">Nam tempus mi eget nunc laoreet venenatis. Proin viverra, erat at accumsan tincidunt, ante mi cursus elit, non</p>

<p class="double">Fogsu</p>
<p class="single">congue mauris dolor ac elit. Maecenas mollis nisl a sem semper ornare. Integer nunc purus, dapibus nec dignissim sed, dictum eget leo. Etiam in mi ut erat pretium fringilla sed</p>
```

Notice that single line breaks are treated differently.  Thanks.

My code so far:

```
print "<p>" . implode( "</p>\n\n<p>", preg_split( '/\n(?:\s*\n)+/', $text ) ) . "</p>";
```

Comment: You could use CKEditor plugin

Comment: @dan I ve been able to achieve wrapping p tags by detecting either a single break or double break. But the problem is to detect both and treat differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$class = 'single';
foreach ($lines as $line) {
     if ( strlen(trim($line)) == 0) {
       $class = 'double';
     } else {
       printf ('<p class="%s">%s</p>'."\n", $class, $line);
       $class = 'single';
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the page prints only one empty p tag with class single

Comment: It helps if I put the arguments in the right order in the `explode` statement. It [works now](http://3v4l.org/lq4Ua).

Comment: Yes seen that already and fixed it also you have to trim the break line, check this out http://codepad.org/3quKblaI

Comment: But am surprised to see yours working without the trim. It works on my box only with the trim. Thanks all the same.

Comment: The `trim` is a good idea. The `explode` eliminates all the `\n` characters, but some systems also add a `\r` character at newlines.

Comment: Yea. Thanks am very greatfull, would have voted you up but I am new here, I haven't gained much reputation. Thansks